# Will adding a transfer grill to the mechanical room help with water heater backdraft?

Tags: hvac, water-heater

I have a small mechanical room in the basement with an HVAC system that has an open return at the base plenum under the furnace blower.

There are no transfer grills and cold air returns to the mechanical room, so it's just sucking up the air in the mechanical room and trying to pull air through gaps in ceiling and under the fire door.  While this is inefficient, the other problem I have is that it's causing backdraft on the water heater in the same mechanical room.

Will adding a fire-rated transfer grill (which was in the original designs) at the mechanical room and another in the hallway stairs up to the first floor fix the backdraft problem by balancing the cold air return using the basement stairwell and hallway as the return path, or is that not enough to counteract the suction the blower would pull against the water neater next to it (which has a pipe to a flue in the old small chimney)?  Could I just run a round flex duct from the return plenum through the mechanical room wall to the basement hallway to fix the backdraft - and make it up to code for penetrating a fire boundary?

I would run a duct up for the cold air return if I could but it's become a Tetris game trying to find the right space in between existing duct work and pipes to run the duct.

[image]

Comment: All of the houses I have ever lived in (over 50 years) which had central air handling and gas furnace/water heater had the return air for the blower ducted out of the 'burn' room into the living spaces where the blower output ducts were going. The blower could easily counteract the air flow requirements of the burners. Your blower needs a full return air duct from the blower opening/box out of the room your water heater is in. I wouldn't experiment where CO poisoning could be a result.

Comment: If I can't find an easy way to run duct into the 1st floor (marked basement in the plan), can I just run duct out of the mechanical burn room into the cellar hallway?